# Create a new DIV element with an image inside it

Tags: javascript, dom, appendchild

I want when I click, a new DIV will be created with an image inside it.

This is the code I tried:

```
let addTask = document.querySelector('#addTask');
addTask.addEventListener('click', ()=>{

         //create DIV, This part of the code works well
    
      let createNewDiv = document.createElement('div');
        createNewDiv.innerHTML = writeTask.value;
        document.body.appendChild(createNewDiv);
        createNewDiv.className = 'tasks';   


     
          //create an image inside the DIV element, This part of the code does not work

      let imageDelete = document.createElement('img');
          imageDelete.src = 'deleteImage.jpg';
          document.body.tasks.appendChild(imageDelete);
});
```

Where's my error?

Any comment or feedback can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
createNewDiv.appendChild(imageDelete)
```

Comment: I have a DIV with specific settings and a specific CLASS NAME. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: document.querySelector(".class-name").appendChild(imageDelete)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are creating an element with a class `.tasks`.
Afterwards you try to access it using `document.body.tasks`.

Elements with a class cannot be accessed directly using this method.
Elements with a id however, can.

So you need to change the `.tasks` element to include the id `tasks` or rewrite the accessor to `document.querySelector('.tasks')`

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector('.tasks').appendChild(imageDelete);
```